# `whitespace: no-wrap` prevents flex-wrap in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

The aim is to have three items per row, but wrapping if the contents of an item is too much to allow this.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGpeXY

```
<div class="FlexContainer">
  <div class="FlexItem">Item 1</div>
  <div class="FlexItem">Item 2</div>
  <div class="FlexItem">Item 3</div>
</div>

<div class="FlexContainer">
  <div class="FlexItem">Item 1</div>
  <div class="FlexItem">Item 2</div>
  <div class="FlexItem">Item 3 Item 3 Item 3 Item 3 Item 3</div>
</div>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.FlexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}

.FlexItem {
    flex: 1 0 33%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: red;
}
```

In Chrome and Firefox (both on OSX), the 'Item 3' flex item wraps as expected:

[image: wrapping in chrome and firefox]

But in Safari (on OSX), the text overflows the container:

[image: no wrapping in safari]

I cannot find a way to get the flex item to wrap in Safari as it does in the other browsers. Any suggestions?

Potentially related to [this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041), but that looks related to interaction with `min-width`, which I'm not setting here. I've raised a new bug [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=165048) but a workaround in the meantime would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the same bug to me just a variation.

Comment: Related, sure, but distinct enough to deserve independent attention/workarounds. Interestingly, setting `min-width` to 33% produces the same issue in Chrome as in Safari.